Strange behaviour using __init_subclass__ with multiple modules
Inspired by an answer about a plugin architecture, I was playing around with PEP-487's subclass registration and found that it led to surprising results when changing the code slightly.
The first step was to split the code from the answer linked above into two files:
$ cat a.py 
class PluginBase:
    subclasses = []
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        print(f'__init_subclass__({cls!r}, **{kwargs!r})')
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.subclasses.append(cls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from b import Plugin1, Plugin2
    print('a:', PluginBase.subclasses)

$ cat b.py 
from a import PluginBase
class Plugin1(PluginBase):
    pass

class Plugin2(PluginBase):
    pass

print('b:', PluginBase.subclasses)

$ python a.py
__init_subclass__(<class 'b.Plugin1'>, **{})
__init_subclass__(<class 'b.Plugin2'>, **{})
b: [<class 'b.Plugin1'>, <class 'b.Plugin2'>]
a: []

I found this output surprising, why is PluginBase's subclasses list empty when printed from a.py, but not from b.py?
Intuitively, I would've written the subclass registration line in a.py as
        PluginBase.subclasses.append(cls)

instead of
        cls.subclasses.append(cls)

because I want to operate on the PluginBase's subclass field rather than the respective Plugin*'s, but that alone didn't give the expected result either.
Then I found that the behaviour could be fixed by simply replacing a.py's line
    from b import Plugin1, Plugin2

to
    from b import *

which, when executing a.py, leads to the output I expected, namely
$ python a.py
__init_subclass__(<class 'b.Plugin1'>, **{})
__init_subclass__(<class 'b.Plugin2'>, **{})
b: [<class 'b.Plugin1'>, <class 'b.Plugin2'>]
a: [<class 'b.Plugin1'>, <class 'b.Plugin2'>]

Can someone enlighten me

Why we write cls.subclasses.append rather than PluginBase.subclasses.append and
What the difference is between from b import * rather than from b import Plugin1, Plugin2 in this context?


I think what might be happening is that when you run from b import * you import the entire namespace and the version of PluginBase from b overrides the local namespace value in a. If you don't do this, and just do from b import Plugin1, Plugin2 the PluginBase in a is never overriden and there's no reason for a.PluginBase to have anything in its subclasses.

"because I want to operate on the PluginBase's subclass field rather than the respective Plugin*'s, but that alone didn't give the expected result either." there is a single attribute that exists in the PluginBase namespace, that attribute is avaialble in the subclasses by inheritance

@NotAName this seems to be the key about the behaviour I experienced, and one I didn't expect - that PluginBase imported from another module could shadow the local PluginBase which is registered in a.py as __main__.PluginBase.

1. Why we write cls.subclasses.append rather than PluginBase.subclasses.append
These two mean different things, and depends on your intention:

cls.subclasses.append means run .subclasses.append looked up from the current class (cls), in which case it executes b.Plugin1.subclasses.append and b.Plugin2.subclasses.append upon subclassing PluginBase. If, as in your example, you don't override the attribute subclasses on b.Plugin1 and b.Plugin2, then it implicitly finds the attribute on PluginBase, so it executes PluginBase.subclasses.append. If you do override the attribute for example with a new list, then the printed list will not include the class:
# b.py
from a import PluginBase

class Plugin1(PluginBase):
    subclasses = []

class Plugin2(PluginBase):
    pass

>>> print("b:", PluginBase.subclasses)  
b: [<class 'b.Plugin2'>]


PluginBase.subclasses.append means run .subclasses.append on PluginBase. It doesn't care what you do with the attribute subclasses in the current class (cls, that is, your b.Plugin1 and b.Plugin2) - you can empty the list, set it to None, ... and you'll always get your b: [<class 'b.Plugin1'>, <class 'b.Plugin2'>].
# b.py
from a import PluginBase

class Plugin1(PluginBase):
    subclasses = []

class Plugin2(PluginBase):
    pass

>>> print("b:", PluginBase.subclasses)  
b: [<class 'b.Plugin1'>, <class 'b.Plugin2'>]




2. What the difference is between from b import * rather than from b import Plugin1, Plugin2 in this context?
The examples you've given demonstrate a workflow bug.
If you're in a directory containing a.py and you run python a.py, you are implicitly creating a module called __main__ and executing the code in a.py inside this module. This is why the code under if __name__ == "__main__" actually runs - __main__ is the name of the module whose code is being executed, not a.
Hence, running python a.py with the following code:
# a.py
class PluginBase:
    subclasses = []
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        print(f'__init_subclass__({cls!r}, **{kwargs!r})')
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.subclasses.append(cls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from b import Plugin1, Plugin2
    print('a:', PluginBase.subclasses)


Executes all of this under a module called __main__ - so you'll have a class called __main__.PluginBase
Imports Plugin1 and Plugin2 from b, which (due to from a import PluginBase) further executes the code in a.py in a module called a. a.PluginBase is the one providing the output b: [<class 'b.Plugin1'>, <class 'b.Plugin2'>].
Prints an empty list at print('a:', PluginBase.subclasses), because PluginBase.subclasses is actually __main__.PluginBase.subclasses - you haven't subclassed __main__.PluginBase anywhere.

When you do from b import *, you override __main__.PluginBase with a.PluginBase due to how star imports work*, hence print('a:', PluginBase.subclasses) gives a: [<class 'b.Plugin1'>, <class 'b.Plugin2'>].
*from b import * will import all names in b which doesn't start with an underscore if b doesn't define a list or tuple of strings named __all__; otherwise it imports all names defined in __all__. Since b imports the name PluginBase from a, b has no object called __all__, and the name PluginBase doesn't start with an underscore, from b import * will implicitly include from b import PluginBase - overriding __main__.PluginBase.

Your entrypoint shouldn't be imported by other modules. This causes this entrypoint to be loaded twice independently, once as __main__ (the module that is initially executed) and another time as a (when the module is imported from b.py).
Normally, when you import a module in another module, that module is looked up in sys.modules by name and if already imported, is simply retrieved instead of created anew each time some module uses some other module. But the entrypoint exists in sys.modules as sys.modules['__main__'], and when the import occurs in b.py the import system doesn't find a sys.modules['a'], it creates a new module.
So, add a print statement **outside the if __name__ == "__main__": guard in your a module, and you'll see it gets executed two different times.
So I change a.py to this:
class PluginBase:
    subclasses = []

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        print(f"__init_subclass__({cls!r}, **{kwargs!r})")
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.subclasses.append(cls)


print("Executing the code in a.py")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from b import Plugin1, Plugin2

    print("a:", PluginBase.subclasses)

And you get:
(py312) Juans-MBP:foo juan$ python a.py
Executing the code in a.py
Executing the code in a.py
__init_subclass__(<class 'b.Plugin1'>, **{})
__init_subclass__(<class 'b.Plugin2'>, **{})
a: []

Now, use namespaced imports and you can compare directly the two different classes, and like this:
# a.py
class PluginBase:
    subclasses = []
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        print(f'__init_subclass__({cls!r}, **{kwargs!r})')
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.subclasses.append(cls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import b
    print("PluginBase is b.PluginBase", PluginBase is b.PluginBase)
    print('a:', PluginBase.subclasses)

And you get:
(py312) Juans-MBP:foo juan$ python a.py
Executing the code in a.py
Executing the code in a.py
__init_subclass__(<class 'b.Plugin1'>, **{})
__init_subclass__(<class 'b.Plugin2'>, **{})
PluginBase is b.PluginBase False
a: []

Note, when you do:
from b import *

The b.PluginBase is assigned to the variable PluginBase in a. So now these will both be referring to the same module object (even though you still created two of them).
